# Spring Boot architecture to reduce dependencies in application parts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

We have a spring boot based application / collection of applications. Already in the first sentence it is complicated to describe it correctly, because from the business view 'the thing' is one application, but from technical view it as a collection of spring boot applications and batch jobs handling use cases of one business software.

For example the software consists of a spring boot application providing a rest-api, multiple spring boot applications providing different web services and multiple batch jobs doing different things based on spring boot applications and other applications.
Now some parts of the code are used only from one of the spring boot applications - so this can be located easily into this particular spring boot application. 
But many parts of the code is used from multiple spring boot applications, but usually less then the half of the applications. For this business code we have a central module imported by all spring boot applications. Adding this central module to a spring boot application increases the big number of dependencies (e.g dependency to a CRM system, dependency to an S3 storage, dependency to generate Excel files, dependency to a external webservice, dependency to rabbit, ...). To avoid the hundreds of dependencies we have defined many as optional. So every spring boot application has only the dependencies it needs.

The problem now is in the central module with the implemented services with business code. These services are injected by autowire. For example a spring boot application providing a webservice interface doesn't need the service to generate Excel files and for that don't have a dependency to the excel libraries and doesn't need to start the excel generation service.

Spring has the possibility to annotate the services with @ConditionalOnClass and @ConditionalOnBean but many of the services doesn't depend only on one condition but on two or more.
So what is the best approach to structure the services to start them only if needed and/or the needed dependencies are available?

At the moment we use @ComponentScan with excludeFilters at every spring boot application but that is error prone. Splitting the central module into multiple modules or microservices is no option because then the modules contains only 1 to 5 classes.

Any good practice to structure applications like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have understood the problem well and broken down into modules enough. In your case to solve this problem of using @ComponentScan with excludeFilters, you must try to do what Spring Boot does with its Auto Configuration mechanism.

For example with the data source configured in properties or yaml file and Spring Boot JPA Starter is in the classpath, Spring Boot Auto Configures everything for us. You need write some custom Starters with logic to Auto Configure your services based on the multiple conditions you have. And in your microservices, batch jobs you can include this custom Starters to enable and inject the necessary Services and those alone.

Sometime back I wrote two blog articles on how to write custom Spring Boot Starters. These could be a good start for you. [Post 1](https://www.techtalks.lk/blog/2018/5/debunking-the-magic-behind-spring-boot) and [Post 2](https://www.techtalks.lk/blog/2018/7/debunking-the-magic-behind-spring-boot-2).

Comment: Unfortunately these are only the basics of spring boot and how to configure in theory, but that's the things I already know. 
What I'm missing is an idea and strategy for a flexible and real world prove concept how to do it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If your module is declaring the common module as a dependency, you can set the scope of that module to 'compile' and then set the dependencies that should be excluded from the common module.

I recently encountered a situation where I required JPA in my common module in order to create generic DAOs for other modules. But I thought it would be wasteful to add a dependency that large my other module that was not utilizing JPA.

This was the solution:

```
<!-- ... -->
    <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>server-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
<!-- ... -->
```

By doing this, in addition to excluding the JPA-related packages in the common module using `@ComponentScan`, the common dependency is included when the server-app module compiles, but does not include the JPA jars with it.

If `@ComponentScan` is not added, the module would still compile, but there would probably be exceptions as soon as a bean is wired from common that attempts to wire a bean from any of the excluded jars.

This is immediately true in my case, since my common module would have attempted to autoconfigure Jpa during startup, if it had not been excluded, because of the the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in `@SpringBootApplication`.